# Can I create a private shop with a public gallery with Magento?

Tags: ecommerce, magento, photo-gallery

I want to do a shop with a public gallery listing all my products, with texts and images. The gallery is not a shop, you cannot buy.

Behind it, I want a private section with a shop, where the same products are listed in tables with all the necessary options to buy. Each customer for the shop will have a separate account.

In the shop and the gallery products are on different page according to their categories.

Is Magento able to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done.

Create your web site, have all of your products listed in a gallery in different categories for your products. You can design this gallery yourself or use WordPress for a little help.

Next, create a private separate product page, subdomain, or Magento hosted eCommerce solution with a required log-in / sign-up page to reach the shop. Customers can view your products through your gallery and then purchase them from you on your Magento product/category page.

I would recommend running your shop on a sub-domain like: `shop.youronlinedomain.com` for Magento.

Comment: with this solution, the gallery is separated from magento, i'd like that the creation of product in magento would impact the shop and the gallery at the same time.

Comment: @Sylario - I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking, could you please clarify your response? It looks as if you are saying that when you create a product in Magento, you want the shop and the gallery to update all at once?

Comment: i want to be able to add a product in one backend, to have it in the "gallery" and in the shop